# Mountain Lion no working gdb debugger

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, debugging, qt-creator

I got a new Macbook Air and installed XCode 5 on it. To my surprise Apple does no longer ship gdb with the command line tools. As I am doing lots of c++ coding I am dependent on a good debugger.

What I tried so far:

Install gdb 7.6 via macports and signed the binary. 
Debugging from QT-Creator is possible. It stops at the breakpoints but I see no information at all about the stack. Using lldb not possible, I get a weird python error.

Debugging from Netbeans is not possible at all. The Debugger is not stopping at any breakpoint. Apart from that Netbeans is not working with lldb.

Working with XCode is no problem. Everything works as expected.

Problem is I need an IDE that can do remote debugging as I have several Raspberry Pi projects. Developing software directly on the pi with vim is fun but not suitable for bigger projects.

So the question is, has anyone a working debugger on Mountain Lion with XCode 5 installed? IDE in question needs to support remote debugging (eg QT-Creator, Netbeans, Eclipse)

Thank you!

Comment: Have you installed the Xcode Command Line tools? `/usr/bin/gdb --version` gives `GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815`.

Comment: Yes of course, but XCode 5 does no longer ship gdb. http://www.mail-archive.com/qt-creator@qt-project.org/msg02421.html

Answer (score 0):

Install Xcode 4.6.3. If you have a developer's account it's available for download at http://developer.apple.com

Comment: Do you mean additionally to XCode 5? Is this possible? Even if it is possible to do it, I would have to downgrade the command line tools as well?!

Comment: Yes, it's quite easy to run multiple copies of xcode. There's even a tool for switch between them. http://wiki.oxygenelanguage.com/en/Working_with_Multiple_Versions_of_Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem. Finally installed command line tools from xcode 4.6.1 on ML. This package is available on Apple site. It installed GCC-LLVM 4.2.1 and GDB 6.5. Qt Creator was able to build application and start debugging. Debugging is not stable too much; but i can to see call stacks, values and stop on breakpoints. I use it for 32bits build - maybe it matters.

Answer (score 0):

You could also switch from GDB to using the LLDB debugger (although the Qt support is early for this).

See http://stanford.edu/~rawatson/lair/mac.html